# Why was "Dynamite Rave" remade?

Tags: videogame-soundtrack, naoki-maeda

Naoki Maeda originally created the song *Dynamite Rave* for [*Dance Dance Revolution 3rdMix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_Dance_Revolution_3rdMix), but it was later redone in either DDR X or DDR X2 (I can't remember which) for "copyright" reasons, apparently due to the lyrics.

This also means that the *Down Bird SOTA Mix*, featuring Sota Fujimori, and the *B4 ZA Beat Mix* were also removed. But there are still songs made by Naoki, which feature lyrics, that are still in the latest mixes of the game, and one of them, called *End Of The Century* is from the exact same mix.

What was the problem with the original *Dynamite Rave*?

Comment: Maybe it's about copyright / law problems so little people can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got an answer from *Zenius-i-Vanisher*, so here goes; It wasn't *Naoki Maeda*'s involvement that was the problem, **it was *Argie Phine* (the rapper) that held a songwriting credit and caused problems in relicensing.** His rap in *End Of the Century* is the reason that was removed as well, albeit at a different time (*Dynamite Rave* was removed in **DDR X AC**, *End Of the Century* was removed in **DDR 2014**), and since that one was less of a fan-favorite, *Konami* and *Bemani* did not commission their new set of singers/rappers to record a new version, while Dynamite Rave was re-made, much to the chagrin of *Dance Dance Revolution* fans...